# Reset session is not working and RDS is currently busy

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-server-2016, rds

Applying reset session /server: example CMD after check query sessions, but still can't access to the remote server.

ERROR :

"The task you are trying to do can't be completed because Remote Desktop Service is currently busy. Please try again in a few minutes. Other users should still be able to log on."

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1: I seen your question on superuser. What are you trying to do? bypass the 2 allowed admin session? You fall offtopic there for such scenario**

Restart all necessary service, like the spooler. RDP is dependant on such.

If the error is still persistant after, watch what GPO apply to the user. I used to get that error on a bad GPP printer mapping, the driver that used to map was putting the server into that state.

So isolate all GPOs to find the root problem

Comment: Because there is no time for me understand?? Restarting the server is a solution that I tried before but I don't wanna use this consistently. I need a different solution you know.

Comment: @mcnsvr Does your users always logoff correctly ? please provide detail is the logoff can happen, or if the profile is locked, that would block any new sessions

Comment: Yes they are doing correctly. Maybe the first thing that I should do, seeing who is active on the server (query sessions like), and wait to logoff these users... Because when I try to log on the server twice, that error shows up. I had almost tried everything..And my IT Manager says; I have not encountered such a mistake throughout his life. Maybe that's what I'm causing :/